# PHP file not working properly on web hosting site

Tags: php, localhost, web-hosting, simple-html-dom

When I run my website on localhost everything works fine, but when I host with atspace.com, simple_html_dom.php doesn't work properly. I can give the code if you need it but does anyone know what the problem may be. Also atspace.com has PHP enabled so I am pretty sure it's not that.

localhost
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjJvA.png

atspace.com
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXkaR.png

**EDIT:** Turns out as I was on a free hosting plan, they didn't allow outgoing http connections or something but hostinger allows it so I am just hosting with them instead now

Comment: Do both localhost and server have same php versions?

Comment: Seems a path issue to me..

Comment: atspace has PHP 5.4.37 - how do I check localhost?

Comment: The folder layout is the same in both though...
http://i.imgur.com/cFB1jA8.png

Comment: It looks, from the error message `file_get_contents(http://blade... ` that you're trying to open an http address in *file_get_contents()*. I'm guessing `allow_url_fopen` is disabled on the server : http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php ... which, to be fair, it probably should be.

Comment: @user2758663 open http://localhost/xampp/ click phpinfo. and tell me the localhost php version

Comment: It's using [PHP: 5.6.3] - should I change atspace.com to use this version?

Comment: If possible, then change it. Its good even in future if both have same version

Comment: Just tried it - didn't make a difference

Comment: Contact your hosts support, as @CD001 suggested it's likely that allow_url_fopen is disabled. You [can use cURL](http://www.christianschenk.org/blog/php-curl-allow-url-fopen/) as an alternative if it is disabled.

Comment: We checked, it's not disabled. [phpinfo()](http://ksa-flight-tracker.tk/)

Comment: Just checked - you get a different error message when `allow_url_fopen` is disabled anyway, namely : *Warning: file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0*

Comment: So what does this mean and how do I resolve it?

Comment: I am new to all this so don't really know what all this is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` may have been disabled in your web hosts PHP config. You need to contact your host. Can your provide a link to a page on the server that contains only the following:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

This will help to confirm it's been disabled.

**EDIT:**
Just ran the following and it worked. Are you using the function like this?

```
<?php
$test = file_get_contents("http://www.blade-edge.com/images/KSA/Flights/craft.asp?r=true&db=dunai");
echo $test;
```

Comment: No, the connection is refused by the remote server.

Comment: In that case, surely the remote host has disabled hotlinking and the likes?

Comment: Yeah, your server config looks okay. It's definitely the remote host. I'm going to try retrieving it from my server. Hang on.

Comment: I am using a file off the internet called simple_html_dom which I believe uses it. My php files however, do not.


http://imgur.com/a/GnHSE

Comment: What does this mean? How can I fix it?